# How can you edit a word document with Java

Tags: java, ms-word

How can you edit a word document with Java?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: +1 for a worthwhile project, but according to their page, the Word aspect is a bit of an afterthought; POI looks like it's focused on Excel.  It can't handle .docx, and it seems they're looking for a project lead on the Word side.  Don't know if that matters to the poster.

Comment: I tried poi and while it can handle simple text docs, if there are images in your original template, poi will lose them.

Comment: docx4j (which I work on) is focused on docx, then pptx, then xlsx in that order. These days POI does support the XML file formats.

Answer (score 4):

You can use COM to do that also. Use a Java COM interop library like JACOB (JAVA COM BRIDGE): http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/

Here is a tutorial using Jacob to talk to MS Word: http://www.land-of-kain.de/docs/jacob/

The other library that looks promising and that will solve the cross-platform problem is J-Interop: http://www.j-interop.org/.

Comment: +1 for Jacob, which has been a lifesaver for me in the past.  But do note that this will lock you into Windows; you wouldn't be able to run a Jacob-based solution on a Unix or Mac box.  No idea if that's a problem for the poster, though.

Answer (score 3):

In the past, I've solved problems like this using [OpenOffice.org](http://openoffice.org)'s Java API.  It's not exactly lightweight, but the licensing terms are generous and it has the backing of a development community with a vested interest in making sure it can parse whatever weirdness Microsoft inflicts on the Word file format.  Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with anything standard. It also depends on the version of Word, since various versions use different file formats.

The [POI project](http://poi.apache.org/) from Apache is supposed to provide ways to do this:

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like [SIKULI](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com), which allows you to populate or produce word docs from Java.  It's based on BlairHippo's suggestion of using the OpenOffice API but without needing to learn the api.  [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) is similar.