# Reading MS doc image from Java

Tags: java, ms-word

I want to read an image embedded in a MS word document using Java. I want to reconstruct the image file.  Can you suggest any java library will hep this task?

Comment: Please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+%22word+document%22) before you read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you edit a word document with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494709/how-can-you-edit-a-word-document-with-java)

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html)  for handling Microsoft Word Files using Java API's

Just a code snippet. Check it out.

```
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.*;
import java.io.*;

public class readDoc
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String filesname = "Hello.doc";
        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
        try
        {
       fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(filesname; 
      //Couldn't close the braces at the end as my site did not allow it to close

                  HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

          WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

          String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();

          System.out.println( "Word Document has " + paragraphs.length + " paragraphs" );
          for( int i=0; i<paragraphs .length; i++ ) {
            paragraphs[i] = paragraphs[i].replaceAll("\\cM?\r?\n","");
                    System.out.println( "Length:"+paragraphs[ i ].length());
          }
                }
                catch(Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question