# How do I call a DOTNET DLL and pass the variable using JAVA applet

Tags: applet, java-native-interface, swig, jacob, jni4net

I have a DLL build in DotNET.

My application is a Java based hosted on the APACHE server and accessed through the web browser on thin client.

Now I will place the DOTNET DLL file on the thin client and not on the server and I want to call this DLL using a JAVA Applet

So when I press a buton on my java based application which is accessed through browser from thin client it should call the DLL file on this machine and pass the variables

Need the expert advise.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to familiarize yourself with ways to call a .dll from java. Afterwards you can embed that into an applet.

Here are things to read for you:

1. [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/)
2. [JNI C+ example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/245622/Using-the-Java-Native-Interface-in-Csharp)
3. Is your library marked as COM visible? Or can you enable that? Then you should have a look at [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)

There are several project you can use:

1. [Swig](http://www.swig.org/)
2. [bridj](https://code.google.com/p/bridj/)
3. [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/)
4. [jnbridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/)
5. [NativeCall](http://johannburkard.de/software/nativecall/)
6. [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports)

Furthermore this question already has been answered before:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009235/getting-jna-to-work-with-java-c/6009272#6009272), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977200/calling-c-sharp-dll-from-java), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647725/using-c-sharp-dll-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743715/how-to-call-into-net-dll-from-java).