# apache poi Word documents (.doc, .docx) updating

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

There seems to be a huge lack of documentation regarding the manipulation of word documents in apache poi (or perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place?)

Is it possible to open a word document and only edit one line/paragraph and then rewrite the document just as it is using poi? Should I even bother with using apache poi, or is there a better supporting library for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is possible with POI. You can find and replace relevant line using poi.
I haven't tried editing documents

[check more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494709/how-can-you-edit-a-word-document-with-java)

and 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/534754/java/java/Editing-pdf-word-content-text

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing... they mention it, but there's really little about it. Don't really know how to even go about it :|

Comment: Is HWPFDocument not part of apache poi 3.10? It doesn't seem to be able to find the imports.

Comment: I haven't used poi.jar for quite while. But it seems to be in their API
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.html

Comment: Sweet, works like a charm. BUT! Microsoft word is complaining saying that the file may be insecure to open and all of that, and won't let me edit it :| any idea what's going on?

Comment: POI support for legacy binary .doc is getting better, slowly... you're probably better off converting to docx (via LO/OO perhaps), then manipulating that (using POI or whatever)