# How to edit word document template using Java

Tags: java, android

I want to edit a word(.docx) template using Java, I am making an android application that uses this feature, please help as i am new to java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:
[How can you edit a word document with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494709/how-can-you-edit-a-word-document-with-java)

Of course when you choose a framework here you have see that you are using a pure java version which run not only on ms windows operating system.
E.g. you could give the openOffice Java API a try.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library for parsing office documents

and here is good tutorial to start with  [Apache POI Word](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_quick_guide.htm)